# How to have a custom navigation in header

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to have a custom navigator, to avoid having a drawer navigator, but I just don't realize why the buttons on the header does not work

```js
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  return {

    headerTitle: ('',
      <Image style={{ width: 150, height: 40 }}
        source={require('./images/image.png')}
      />
    ),
    headerLeft: (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={navigator.getParam('menu')}>
        <Image style={{ width: 50, height: 40 }}
          source={require('./images/hamburger_icon.png')}
        />
      </TouchableHighlight>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your mistake is on the line of `TouchableHighlight`, specifically on `onPress={navigator.getParam('menu')}`

You should have this instead: `onPress={navigation.getParam('menu')}`

Be careful with the logic of navigator, it is easy to get confused with `navigation` and `navigator`

Let me know if that works.